# Comic navigation in joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have a joomla site and would like to integrate some old unfinished webcomics to it, so I can pick them up where I stopped in a CMS that won't leave me in an absolute frothing rage (thanks, wordpress).

I've got some experience with Joomla and I believe it would be a pretty good platform for managing multiple comics... except for the small issue of *horrid* navigation between pages/articles. Joomla's integrated article navigation is a humble but passable start, but if you intend to use categories to organize chapters then getting from the end of one to the beginning of the next is... yeah. This is a pity, as Joomla's category and article management options are beautiful for archiving and presentation, and adding gantry 5 to it means a great deal of control over the reading experience. Basically, joomla has pretty much everything I want, except for the navigation.

Ideally, what I'd like to be able to accomplish for comic navigation in joomla is:

- Clickable full-article-image leading to next article/page
- Prev/next article buttons (already available)
- Prev/next category buttons (do we have those?)
- The latter two in a module I can choose where to publish (optional)

And this is it, basically. I understand that implementing the first could be very hard without some major template customization, in which case I'd be willing to insert the image as a link in the article body... but only if there was one single code I could use, like the one that generates the *next* category article button. Because I'm not willing to create hundreds of menu items to generate links page-by-page.

So is any of this doable?

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick answer but too much for a comment. I'm assuming since you are on SO that you don't mind coding (as opposed to just configuring).

I think you need to do two things. First you need to create a pagination.php for your template. This will let you really super control what the pagination looks like. You can have images, special css and js, whatever you want. You can also add the "last" and "first" options. 
 I think you need to make a new plugin to replace the core pagenavigation plugin and that also generates the previous/next category links. (Or I guess you could make one just to do categorynavigation depending on what you want.)  HOWEVER, it seems to me that there is data on the sibling links that is already being generated in the content category model so you might be able to use that. (Check the code; I think there was never a UI for it, but it is there. Even if it isn't there, siblings are very easy to obtain in nested sets)

The other thing you can really think about if you go that route is changing the whole thing somewhat to use a module that gets the current ID  and category ID from JInput. You might also be able to use JPagination.  The important thing, however is that you make sure to do the caching the way the pagination that is there does it. In other words you really want to cache the whole list in the order you want so you are not running so many queries and slowing your site down. You may want to look at the categories and category modules to get some ideas about the queries to do.

Hope that gets you started, but it is definitely something you can do without too much trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't mind coding, but I am definitely very much an amateur, and most of that stuff is definitely beyond me atm. Still, just knowing it's doable takes a weight off my chest-- if it's possible, then it's learnable. I guess it's time to crack my knuckles and dig in, right?

Comment: Yes! And you will be surprised that it is not that hard. You can copy a lot of the code from elsewhere.  For example for the pagination.php get the basic concept from Protostar (in the html folder).  And for the plugin just copy the exisitng plugin to a new name (and go through and change the old name to the new name everywhere).  Take a look at the documentation web site.

Comment: I'll be honest, I opened the protostar pagination.php the other day and felt like i'd just walked into a spelling bee for medical taxonomy... Thanks for the plugin tip, by the way, as I don't think I would have thought of that.